# Problem with Android Crash on Google Play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have really short stacktrace from Google Play Console. I can see that it causes thousands of crashes in my production app.
From user side, after icon click app is starting and crashes immediately.
I can't reproduce it on demand.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3121)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3264)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute 
  (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks 
  (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute 
  (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1955)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7078)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
  (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

I have no idea what I could change to have some more information in this stacktrace.
Of course other stacktraces (from other bugs) are richer than that.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using another crash reporting tool such as Firebase Crashlytics as it gives much more detailed crash reports than Google Play and will help you easier reproduce the issue. This is because Google Play reduces the contents of the stack trace due to Privacy legislation such as GDPR.